# Session vs (re)include for faster page loading

Tags: php, performance, session, include

Could someone say what´s the fastest way to load a page content: Reincludind repetitive content on every page loading or storing it as a session?

I want to include a static menu. So it should be required on every page of my website. Would someone recomend require it once and store it as a session to improve the speed for the next pages loadings?

I.e:

**Page 1**

```
<?php

require('inc/menu.php'); 

$_SESSION['menu'] = $sMenu;

//content goes here

?>
```

**Page 2, 3 , 4, n...**

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['menu'])){
$sMenu = $_SESSION['menu']
}

else{
require('inc/menu.php'); 
}

//content goes here

?>
```

Note that the menu is just an example. It could be used for other includes anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So did you try to benchmark times for both ways and do a comparison for speed atleast?

Comment: $_SESSION is stored on the FILESYSTEM. so this will always be slower. But then again, this is a micro optimisation that will NEVER add performance. And, instead of  simply including a file. You introduced 2 possible branches and are clogging the $_SESSION file.

Comment: If you want faster page loading try HTTP caching.